# c# on and off switch not changing

Tags: c#

firstly thanks for taking your time to give me a hand.

So here is what I'm trying to do, I have a on / off switch.

If it's checked it has a tick.
If it's not checked it has a cross.

So I'm trying to make the Visibility set to false if it's got a cross and visibility to true if it's got a tick.

Here is my code.

```
        private void on_off_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (on_off.Checked == true) return;
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
            statistics_text.Visible = true;
        }

        if (on_off.Checked == false) return;
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = false;
            statistics_text.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

But for some strange reason this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's with the `return`s?

Comment: Of what type is the on/off switch object/control?

Comment: it's a control to operate if the groupbox & text are visible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your code, formatted so you can see more easily what's going on:

```
if (on_off.Checked == true)
    return;

groupBox1.Visible = true;
statistics_text.Visible = true;

if (on_off.Checked == false)
    return;

groupBox1.Visible = false;
statistics_text.Visible = false;
```

I can't imagine you want to just return if the CheckBox is checked.

This is more likely what you wanted. Remove the `return` statement and make sure only one block or the other execute with an `else` statement.

```
if (on_off.Checked == true)
{
    groupBox1.Visible = true;
    statistics_text.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    groupBox1.Visible = false;
    statistics_text.Visible = false;
}
```

Even more succinctly:

```
groupBox1.Visible = on_off.Checked;
statistics_text.Visible = on_off.Checked;
```

Comment: Was just going to comment with the exact first code you provided, seems the returns where not needed. Seen them on some other question here that's why I added the,

Comment: @JohnDueDueDue The point of this answer is that the code inside the blocks `{ }` was *not* associated with the `if` statements in any way, because those blocks did not *immediately* follow them.